# How can I start a long-running jobs in Catalyst with progress bar?

Tags: perl, progress-bar, catalyst

How would I start a long-running job from within a Catalyst app? I want a page from which the user can upload a list of URLs, and the application would then go and download these URLs. I need to implement an AJAX progress indicator that would then show the status of this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try [Catalyst::Plugin::UploadProgress](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Plugin-UploadProgress/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/UploadProgress.pm).  Its intended to be used for file uploads, but I'm thinking it can be used for what you're doing as well since you're downloading the URL (which is honestly like uploading a file to the server anyways).

Comment: I linked it.  Why would I need to regurgitate something here that a user can read through the link?

Comment: This looks good, I can use its code as a reference for how to implement progress reporting. Thanks!